# Typescript Array Push

Tags: arrays, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

Everyone hello,

I am facing a problem that I can not find a solution for about 3 days.

To summarize my problem, I have an Array with 10 capacities, and I want to update it with a function and add another 10, so I want to push the other array to an array.

The function I wrote about this is as follows;

```
posts: Array<Post> = new Array<Post>();
```

this posts have 10 posts before because getorderbydateposts worked one time when page opened.

Function

```
 doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    let page = (Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10)) + 1;

    this.wordpressService.getOrderByDatePosts(page)
    .subscribe(
      (posts:Array<Post>) => {
        console.log("Before push");
        console.log(this.posts);

        console.log("More new array");
        console.log(posts);

        for(var post of posts)
        {
          this.posts.push(post);
        }

        console.log("After push");
        console.log(this.posts);
        
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      } ,
      (error) =>console.error(error)
    );
  }
```

Here is the response I got from this code. It looks like the size of the Array is fixed and does not change. What is the reason of this ? Does anyone have such an error?

[Response Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1msY.png)

Comment: Where and how do you declare and use `this.posts`?

Comment: Globally in the Class page like this https://ibb.co/d6gQs6

Comment: Could it be that the async get function works for async?